# How to fine tune search results that contain most searching words in Elasticsearch 6.8?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6.8

Below is my mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "text": { 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": { 
              "type":     "keyword",
              "normalizer": "case_insensitive"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Settings look like following:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis" : {
        "normalizer" : {
          "case_insensitive" : {
            "filter" : "lowercase"
          }
        },
        "analyzer" : {
          "en_std" : {
            "type" : "standard",
            "stopwords" : "_english_"
          }
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "hawaii beach 2019",
          "analyze_wildcard: true,
          "fields": [
            "text"
          ]
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Below is sample data which is stored in Elasticsearch:

```
[
  {
     "text": "blue hawaii hotel"
  },
  {
     "text": "costa beach"
  },
  {
     "text": "white hawaii beach"
  },
  {
     "text": "nice hotel 2019"
  },
  {
     "text": " some 2019 white beach hawaii photo"
  },
  {
     "text": "hawaii vacation 2019"
  },
]
```

If my searching word is `hawaii`, I get three results which are:

```
[
  {
     "text": "blue hawaii hotel"
  },
  {
     "text": "white hawaii beach"
  },
  {
     "text": " some 2019 white beach hawaii beach photo"
  },
]
```

If my searching word is `hawaii beach`, I get four results which are:

```
[
  {
     "text": "blue hawaii hotel"
  },
  {
     "text": "costa beach"
  },
  {
     "text": "white hawaii beach"
  },
  {
     "text": " some 2019 white beach hawaii photo"
  },
]
```

If my searching word is `hawaii beach 2019`, I get five results which are:

```
[
  {
     "text": "blue hawaii hotel"
  },
  {
     "text": "costa beach"
  },
  {
     "text": "white hawaii beach"
  },
  {
     "text": "nice hotel 2019"
  },
  {
     "text": " some 2019 white beach hawaii photo"
  },
]
```

This is because each record contains one word of the searching text. It makes sense but it is not exactly what I want. I want that the record which contains most matching words appears on top of the search results and record which contains less matching word appears at the bottom of the search results. How can I do that in Elasticsearch 6.8? If this cannot be realized, showing only record which contains most matching words is also desired as search results.

Desired search results if my search text is e.g. `hawaii beach 2019`:

```
[
  {
     "text": " some 2019 white beach hawaii photo" // Contains most matching words.
  },
  {
     "text": "white hawaii beach"
  },
  {
     "text": "blue hawaii hotel" // Contains less matching words.
  },
  {
     "text": "costa beach" // Contains less matching words.
  },

  {
     "text": "nice hotel 2019" // Contains less matching words.
  },

]
```

or

```
[
  {
     "text": " some 2019 white beach hawaii photo" // Contains most matching words
  },
]
```

Comment: I tested your configuration and query and everything is working well in my tests. `some white beach hawaii 2019 photo` is the best scored document, next is `white hawaii beach` and so on.

Comment: What are the scores you get for each document?

Comment: I have added one more sample record into Elasticsearch: `{"text": "hawaii vacation 2019"}`. Can you add this extra record and try again with searching text `hawaii beach 2019`? I am afraid you then will get `hawaii vacation 2019` first even `some 2019 white beach hawaii photo` contains most matching words.

Comment: My point is that Elasticsearch gives the last word of the searching text more scores than documents that contain most matching words.

Comment: How many shards does your index have? How many documents? And, again, what are the scores Elasticsearch gives you in the results?

Comment: How are you executing the query?

Comment: @AndreiStefan when executing `curl -X GET -d '{"from": 0, "size": 1000, "query": {"match_all": {}} }'`, I get `"_shards" : { "total" : 5,   "successful" : 5,   "skipped" : 0,  "failed" : 0}`. I have 17 documents. The score of each found document is always 1.0. This is when I retrieve all documents without searching operations.

Comment: @mihomir  `{
   "query": {
       "bool": {
         "must": {
           "bool": {
             "should": {
               "query_string": {
                 "query": "hawaii beach 2019",
                 "analyze_wildcard": true,
                 "fields": text
               }
             }
           }
         }
      }
   }
 }`

Comment: @mihomir This query works almost right, unfornately, I missed one document which is `{"text": "costa beach"}`.

Comment: I meant if you are executing the query in Kibana or via curl or some other way. Because when I tried the answer that says to use AND between the words, it worked for me as you want it: it returns only the result "some 2019 white beach hawaii photo".

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your input query:

```
hawaii AND beach AND 2019
```

Then you will get results with all 3 words.

Comment: According to [query_string manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) there is also an option to use double quotes.
Query `"hawaii beach 2019"` will search for all the words in the phrase, in the same order.

Comment: I did try `AND` between words. It shows the same results as without `AND`. All records which contains one of these words are retrieved and shown. Records which contains most matching words did not appear on top of the search result. The same to records which contains less match words also did not appear at the bottom of the search results.

Comment: This is really strange because it is mentioned in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators)


> By default, all terms are optional, as long as one term matches. 
> A search for foo bar baz will find any document that contains one or more of foo or bar or baz

Comment: Can you try such query: `+hawaii +beach +2019`?

Comment: Using `+` sign prefixing each word does not have any effect. Search results remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a work-around solution by surrounding each word in the searching string by `*` as following.

```
{ 
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": { 
        "bool": { 
          "should": { 
            "query_string": { 
              "query": "*hawaii* *beach* *2019*", 
              "fields": ["text"]
            } 
          } 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

With this query I get all documents which contains at least one word of the searching string. Documents with most matching searching words appear on top of the list.

Comment: The bool part of the query is unnecessary, you can rewrite it simply as { 
  "query": { 
    "query_string": { 
      "query": "\*hawaii\* \*beach\* \*2019\*", 
      "fields": ["text"]
    } 
  } 
}

Comment: You are right! Just in case people want to add more query filters.